# CassandraSqlContext insert into cassandra table command unable to insert all rows into cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax

I'm trying to insert aggregated values into cassandra CF using `CassandraSQLContext`.

Here is the sample code.

```
val cc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
cc.sql("insert into table xxxx select * from yyyy")
```

Here xxxx  supposed to get 63000 rows from yyyy CF. But in my case above command is inserting only half of the records into xxxx CF.

I would like to know if there is any setting to handle this in datastax? or with `SPARK`?

Answer (score 0):

The bast way to debug your cassandra code is to using cqlsh command line. You could simple run "insert into table xxxx select * from yyyy" in cqlsh command line, there maybe some error message for that if not success. Then you could know how to workaround that.